# debootstrap fails to download Debian squeeze

Tags: debian

I'm trying to use debootstrap to create a debian32 system and compile the kernel there but I'm not capable off.

```
root@citsnmaiko-deb:~# debootstrap  --verbose --arch i386 squeeze /opt/chroots/debian32/ http://ftp.debian.org/debian/
I: Retrieving Release
E: Failed getting release file http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/Release
root@citsnmaiko-deb:~#
```

I'm behind a proxy but apt-get and wget works fine, I already tryied to set the http_proxy var but without success.

what else can I do ?

Comment: You mention that `apt-get` works fine.  Is `ftp.debian.org` the mirror you are using in your sources.list?  Are you perhaps using ftp instead of http?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the right command. Your question appears to be just "what else can I do ?" (sic).

So here are a few reasons why this might happen.

- Unreachability of ftp.debian.org from your machine
- Unexplained error on ftp.debian.org

Can you:

- resolve the name?
- successfully make a tcp connection to it on port 80?
- retreive that file?

Try using `nc` or `curl` to pull the file. Run `tcpdump` in another terminal and see what happens.

Comment: I changed the mirror and export my http_proxy. Now its working. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Lets help someone with Google foo. Same error but different cause

```
root@vm-lucid:/tmp/ramfs# debootstrap lucid here http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
I: Retrieving Release
E: Failed getting release file http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/Release
```

Typical debug step, proves network / proxy / mirror is okay... so now what?

`wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/Release`

Adding `set -x` to `just_get` in `/usr/share/debootstrap/functions`
and logging via `if ! just_get "$from" "$dest2" > /tmp/debootstrap_hidden_log 2>&1; then continue; fi` reveals something interesting!

```
+ set -x
+ local from=http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/Release
...
+ wget -q -O /tmp/ramfs/here/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/debootstrap.invalid_dists_lucid_Release http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/Release
Can't be verbose and quiet at the same time.
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...
+ ret=1
...
```

Why would one get that error message???

SOLUTION: Remove `verbose=on` from wgetrc, that a user forgot in there years ago...